# Swift-Rss project-Can't get img src link inside CDATA blocks

Tags: regex, xml, swift, rss, cdata

I have a very annoying problem. I am developing an RSS Reader for Swift(with Xcode 7.1). i want each cell of my tableview show images for each news. Here is my code:

```
     cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
     let news = items[indexPath.row] as MWFeedItem?
        if news?.content != nil {

        let htmlContent = news!.content as NSString
        var imageSource = ""

        let rangeOfString = NSMakeRange(0, htmlContent.length)
        let regex = try? NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: [])

        if htmlContent.length > 0 {
            let match = regex?.firstMatchInString(htmlContent as String, options: [], range: rangeOfString)

            if match != nil {
                let imageURL = htmlContent.substringWithRange(match!.rangeAtIndex(2)) as NSString
                print(imageURL)

                if NSString(string: imageURL.lowercaseString).rangeOfString("feedburner").location == NSNotFound {
                    imageSource = imageURL as String

                               }

                                }
        }

        if imageSource != "" {
            cell.itemImageView.setImageWithURL(NSURL(string: imageSource)!, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder"))
       }
   else{
           cell.itemImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder")
       }

    }
```

So, the problem is that: when the rss feed xml file doesn't have CDATA blocks, my code works perfectly; in other most cases it doesn't work because inside xml file there is a structure like this:

```
<![CDATA[<p><a href="http://firenze.repubblica.it/cronaca/2015/11/12/news/la_denuncia_dei_genitori_di_una_scuola_di_firenze_la_mostra_divina_bellezza_vietata_ai_bambini_-127167480/?rssimage"> <img src="http://www.repstatic.it/content/nazionale/img/2015/11/12/115530091-51ce67c2-7b38-41c1-8aa5-21d51b157335.jpg" width="140" align="left" hspace="10"></a>I genitori contro la scelta del consiglio interclasse delle terze elementari dell'istituto Matteotti di fermare la gita all'esposizione "Divina Bellezza" sul...</p>]]></description><guid isPermaLink="true"><!
```

It's clear that CDATA block doesn't let me read img src link. What can i do?
Thank in advance for your help!

Comment: better paste xml contents as a whole so that we know which part of the contents that you would like to grab

Comment: Here is the full xml code:http://www.repubblica.it/rss/homepage/rss2.0.xml  i need string inside <img src="" or inside <enclosure url"". In few words i need the image link.

Comment: is it that if <img src="" is within CDATA, then your regex fails to match the src url?

Comment: Yes,exactly. what can i do?

Comment: you may refer to my answer below, your regex is totally fine, you just need to get all the matches out from it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run the following code in the PlayGround using your regex and successfully got all the img src urls from the xml.

```
import Foundation

let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.repubblica.it/rss/homepage/rss2.0.xml")!
let xml = try String(contentsOfURL: url)
let regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(<img.*?src=\")(.*?)(\".*?>)", options: [])
let range = NSMakeRange(0, xml.characters.count)
regex.enumerateMatchesInString(xml, options: [], range: range) { (result, _, _) -> Void in
  let nsrange = result!.rangeAtIndex(2)
  let start = xml.startIndex.advancedBy(nsrange.location)
  let end = start.advancedBy(nsrange.length)
  print(xml[start..<end])
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the advice! now i have another problem: if i use my first post regex after yours, giving as input xml value, it return me the same image for all the cell! How can i do to show right image for each news? thanks in advice!

Comment: you should use the stuff I printed with your tableview. Save them into an array and implement your datasource delegate methods

Comment: Can you link me a similar implementation project? i'm new to Swift.

Comment: http://www.codingexplorer.com/getting-started-uitableview-swift/
Articles like this will teach you how to use UITableView